# How can I use the '*' , i.e. 'match zero or more', in regular expressions with a pipe (OR)?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have written this regular expression:

```py
import re

sentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."

myRegex = re.compile(
    r"(\w|\s)*"        #Ideally, zero or more (space characters or word characters) 
    r"(quick brown)"
)
matches = myRegex.findall(sentence)

print(matches)
```

I would expect there to be `[('The ', 'quick brown')]` printed to the screen, which I what I want ideally, but instead I get `[(' ', 'quick brown')]`.

Similarly, I also tried changing the regex to:

```py
myRegex = re.compile(
    r"((\w|\s)*)"  
    r"(quick brown)"
)
```

This results in a print of : `[('The ', ' ', 'quick brown')]`, which is closer than before to what I would like, but has the second group, which seems inefficient as it is just the space character.

Comment: `*` is match *zero* or more.

Comment: Oops.. that was a typo - thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct expression really depends on what you are trying to do...

- Do you want the first word preceding `quick brown`? Try this:

  ```
  sentence = "This is the quick brown fox who jumps over the lazy dog."

  myRegex = re.compile(
      r"(\w+)\s*"
      r"(quick brown)"
  )

  print(myRegex.findall(sentence))

  # Result: [('the', 'quick brown')]
  ```
- Do you also want the spaces after the word? Try this:

  ```
  myRegex = re.compile(
      r"(\w+\s*)"
      r"(quick brown)"
  )    

  # Output: [('the ', 'quick brown')]
  ```
- Do you want the whole *group of words* before `quick brown`? Try this:

  ```
  myRegex = re.compile(
      r"([\w\s]+)"
      r"(quick brown)"
  )

  # Result: [('This is the ', 'quick brown')]
  ```

Either way, the use of the `*` token (zero or more) is not needed for `\w` here, and can cause problems in edge cases when no words are matched.

Answer (score 2):

(\w|/s) indicates that the first group contains only one character.so as if whole re matches “The quick brown”, the first group is a space, because you have only one char in the first parentheses.

Comment: r”([\w\s]*)(quick brown)”  maybe